# JAXB - Set an XmlAdapter only for an specific sub type of an element?

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I have to generate a xml element  that can have as value any "primitive type" (xsd:string, xsd:boolean, etc). Examples:

```
<field xsi:type="xsd:string" name="aString">String Value</field>
<field xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" name="aDate">2011-10-21</field>
<field xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" name="aDateTime">2011-10-21T12:00:00</field>
...
```

So, I use this implementation that makes JAXB decide the `xsi:type` of the primitive type:

```
public class Field {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    Object value;
}
```

and it is working as expected but all the java.util.Date gets the type `xs:dateTime` ...

Now I want to change the behavior of the marshaller ONLY when the 'value' object is an instance of java.util.Date to obtains fields like this:

```
<field xsi:type="xsd:date" name="aDate">2011-10-21</field>
<field xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" name="aDateTime">2011-10-21T12:00:00</field>
```

So I create an adapter, but if I try this:

```
@XmlElement
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
Object value;
```

The adapter must handles a java.lang.Object type

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Object> {...}
```

But I do not want to loose the JAXB marshallers for all the others objects (Integer, Double, etc) ...

there is a way to set an adapter for a specific subtype of an element?

Comment: No really ... I've an adapter that handles the Object class and internally manage each subtype. Is not "nice", but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation though I was comming from the XSD and generating the classes from there.  That said, the solution should be transposable to you as well.

In my cases I wanted to extend the usage of a simple String in the XSD model so that it comes out as a UUID in the Java code, then another would come out as a Class in other places and so on. XML side, it's all string (xs:string), so how to get all these strings into separate types java side...

What I ended doing is, in the XSD I created simple types for each cases, here the UUID declaration :

And use this instead of a String whereever required.

I then created a bindings file where I specified my XmlAdaptors, much as you did, except now I have separate targets and thus can use multiple adaptors targetted specifically to each xml "types".

Now, you have an additionnal difficulty here is that on the Java side the representation of your field is just an object.  I suppose you then cast it once you know the type attribute.  Perhaps creating a subclass of field for each cases, this would allow you to change the typeADaptor declaration.

Answer (score -1):

try

http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html#Use__XmlJavaTypeAdapter

XmlJavaTypeAdapter for interfaces with multiple implementations

Comment: -1 Did you read the question? I did implement a `XmlAdapter<String, Object>` but with this I loose the adapter for `Integer, Double, etc`. What I want is to keep those adapters, and obviously if I use an adapter for object the easier thing to do is to generate a `xsi:anyType` but that is exactly what I do not want to

Comment: Regarding your "multiple implementations" solution, that implies that I have to handle and adapter for `Object` and implement a wrapper for each object subclass to generate the correct `xsi:type`. Again, here I'm loosing the adapters that I want to keep.